# Apache Thrift not installing on Mac

Tags: java, c, macos, protocol-buffers, thrift

Mac OSX 10.10.5 (Yosemite) here. I am trying to find a tool that will:

1. Given a definition/config file, generate a native C network/socket client (library); and
2. Given a definition/config file, generate a Java network/socket server

In reality both artifacts will be ran (likely) on the same machine, but one *has* to be native C and the other *has* to be Java.

I *believe* [Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org) is a tool that can do this job, but if it's not, or if there are other/better/easier tools to use, then I'm certainly open to other recommendations.

---

Right off the bat, I sort of expected Thrift to come in some kind of distribution, ready to be ran as-is. Instead, according to the [documentation](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/BuildingFromSource) it looks like you have to build it yourself. Enter the pain.

I downloaded the tarball (`v0.9.3`) and then navigated to the unpacked directory. Then I run `./configure` (as those docs state to do), which produces an enormous amount of output, most suspiciously:

```
Building C++ Library ......... : yes
Building C (GLib) Library .... : no     <--- heh?
Building Java Library ........ : no     <--- heh?
Building C# Library .......... : no
Building Python Library ...... : yes
Building Ruby Library ........ : no
Building Haxe Library ........ : no
Building Haskell Library ..... : no
Building Perl Library ........ : yes
Building PHP Library ......... : yes
Building Erlang Library ...... : no
Building Go Library .......... : no
Building D Library ........... : no
Building NodeJS Library ...... : yes
Building Lua Library ......... : no
```

Now I don't know *anything* about Thrift, but to me, that looks like it's **not** building out "libraries"/"generators"/etc. for C or Java, the two lanaguages I'm specifically interested in!!! **(1) Any ideas as to why?**

Next, the instructions state to run `make`, which produces indecipherable compiler errors:

```
...blah blah blah lots of compiler output, blah blah blah...

src/thrift/transport/TSSLSocket.cpp:147:24: error: use of undeclared identifier 'TLSv1_1_method'; did you mean 'TLSv1_method'?
    ctx_ = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_1_method());
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                       TLSv1_method

src/thrift/transport/TSSLSocket.cpp:149:24: error: use of undeclared identifier 'TLSv1_2_method'; did you mean 'TLSv1_method'?
    ctx_ = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_2_method());
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                       TLSv1_method

74 warnings and 2 errors generated.
make[4]: *** [src/thrift/transport/TSSLSocket.lo] Error 1
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**(2) Any idea how to troubleshoot here?!?**

This seems like I'm going 3 sides around the barn. In other areas of the documentation, I need to build several other libraries (Boost and `libevent`), and I ran into all sorts of headaches with the instructions for those builds as well (e.g. the version of `libevent` didn't like the version of Bison that I had that ships by default with Mac, etc.).

Does Thrift come as a fully-ready-to-go app that I can just run on Mac OS? Why do I need to go through the motions of all this building?

So most importantly: **(3) If it exists, where can I find a ready-to-run Thrift Mac executable? And if it does not exist, are there other tools out there that are easier to install/run?**

Comment: Re `TLSv1_1_method` => [THRIFT-2515](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-2515). Did cost me 10 seconds googling it, first hit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the end, it was as simple as:

`brew install thrift`

Comment: After experimenting with Thrift for a few days I ultimately found Google's Protocol Buffers to be easier to use, configure and to be faster than Thrift which appears to be a dead or dying project.